# EitherT throws compilation error when returning child class

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In the code below I'm using cats' `EitherT` class. It compiles, but I was forced to use the `Error` trait in:

```
def isNeg(i:Int): Future[Either[Error,Int]] = Future {
```

where my intent was to declare the function as:

```
def isNeg(i:Int): Future[Either[IsPositive,Int]] = Future {
```

but if I use `IsPositive` (the class returned in the function's `Left`) Scala throws a compilation error. Why doesn't it compile with `IsPositive` ?

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.implicits._

trait Error
case class IsNegative() extends Error
case class IsPositive() extends Error

object HelloScala extends App {

    def isPos(i:Int): Future[Either[IsNegative,Int]] = Future {
      if (i>0)
          Right(i)
      else
          Left(IsNegative())
    }

    def isNeg(i:Int): Future[Either[Error,Int]] = Future {
      if (i<0)
          Right(i)
      else
          Left(IsPositive())
    }

    def myFunction (i: Int) = {
       val result = for {
          ret <- EitherT(isPos(i)) // <-- compilation error, if IsPositive is used in isNeg
          ret2 <- EitherT(isNeg(ret))
       } yield ret2
       println(result.value)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does `yield` works? It is translated to `flatMap` (see [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)). So, let's try to rewrite your case with `flatMap` and with explicit types for non-compilable version:

```
val eithert1: EitherT[Future, IsNegative, Int] = EitherT(isPos(i))
def eithert2(ret: Int): EitherT[Future, IsPositive, Int] = EitherT(isNeg(ret))
eithert1.flatMap(ret => eithert2(ret)).map(ret2 => ret2)
```

And now what types you have:

```
// What is expected (see `EitherT` type bounds in sources, I copied here)
// flatMap -> EitherT[F[_], A, B].flatMap[AA >: A, D](f: B => EitherT[F, AA, D])
// what you have:
// EitherT[Future, IsNegative, Int].flatMap[IsPositive >: IsNegative, Int](f: Int => EitherT[Future, IsPositive, Int])
```

You see: `IsPositive >: IsNegative`, which is wrong. Expected super-type for `IsNegative` (either `Error` or `IsNegative`)